# Debugging a program without source code (Unix / GDB)

Tags: debugging, unix, gdb

This is homework. Tips only, no exact answers please.

I have a compiled program (no source code) that takes in command line arguments. There is a correct sequence of a given number of command line arguments that will make the program print out "Success." Given the wrong arguments it will print out "Failure."

One thing that is confusing me is that the instructions mention two system tools (doesn't name them) which will help in figuring out the correct arguments. The only tool I'm familiar with (unless I'm overlooking something) is GDB so I believe I am missing a critical component of this challenge.

The challenge is to figure out the correct arguments. So far I've run the program in GDB and set a breakpoint at `main` but I really don't know where to go from there. Any pro tips?

Comment: On what OS (precisely) ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have to debug it? It would be easier to disassemble it. When you disassemble it look for `cmp`

Answer (score 1):

1. There exists not only tools to decompile X86 binaries to Assembler code listings, but also some which attempt to show a more high level or readable listing. Try googling and see what you find. I'd be specific, but then, that would be counterproductive if your job is to learn some reverse engineering skills.
2. It is possible that the code is something like this:  If Arg(1)='FOO' then print "Success".  So you might not need to disassemble at all. Instead you only might need to find a tool which dumps out all strings in the executable that look like sequences of ASCII characters.  If the sequence you are supposed to input is not in the set of characters easily input from the keyboard, there exist many utilities that will do this.  If the program has been very carefully constructed, the author won't have left "FOO" if that was the "password" in plain sight, but will have tried to obscure it somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would start with an `ltrace` of the program with any arbitrary set of arguments.  I'd then use the `strings` command and guess from that what some of the hidden argument literals might be.  (Let's assume, for the moment, that the professor hasn't encrypted or obfuscated the strings and that they appear in the binary as literals).  Then try again with one or two (or the requisite number, if number).

If you're lucky the program was compiled and provided to you without running `strip`.  In that case you might have the symbol table to help.  Then you could try single stepping through the program (read the `gdb` manuals).  It might be tedious but there are ways to set a breakpoint and tell the debugger to run through some function call (such as any from the standard libraries) and stop upon return.  Doing this repeatedly (identify where it's calling into standard or external libraries, set a breakpoint for the next instruction after the return, let gdb run the process through the call, and then inspect what the code is doing besides that.

Coupled with the `ltrace` it should be fairly easy to see the sequencing of the `strcmp()` (or similar) calls.  As you see the string against which your input is being compared you can break out of the whole process and re-invoke the `gdb` and the program with that one argument, trace through 'til the next one and so on.  Or you might learn some more advanced `gdb` tricks and actually modify your argument vector and restart `main()` from scratch.

It actually sounds like fun and I might have my wife whip up a simple binary for me to try this on.  It might also create a little program to generate binaries of this sort.  I'm thinking of a little #INCLUDE in the sources which provides the "passphrase" of arguments, and a make file that selects three to five words from /usr/dict/words, generates that #INCLUDE file from a template, then compiles the binary using that sequence.